# ionic-angular PWA Service Worker prevents app to initial when redirecting (only on chrome)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Hi everyone Im currently working on an Angular 15 - Ionic 5 PWA with a payment procedure.
But when redirecting to app from Bank after payment is done, Service worker prevents app to initial and gives 405 not allowed error back as it shows below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EukG0.png)

But its happens only on chrome browser and it works fine on others.
This is how ngsw-config.json looks like:

```
{"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
   {
     "name": "app",
     "installMode": "prefetch",
     "resources": {
     "files": [
      "/favicon.ico",
      "/index.html",
      "/manifest.webmanifest",
      "/*.css",
      "/*.js"
    ]
   }},
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
      "files": [
      "/assets/**",
      "/*.(svg|cur|jpg|jpeg|png|apng|webp|avif|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)"
    ]
  }
}],
      "dataGroups": [{
      "name": "myDataGroup",
      "urls": ["/auth"],
      "cacheConfig": {
      "maxSize": 40,
      "maxAge": "3d12h"
    }}
  }]}
```